# Ubuntu live USB cannot boot - Manjaro boots successfully with same media

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, windows-10, rufus

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 as a dual boot alongside Windows 10. After I downloaded an Ubuntu iso file and wrote it to a USB with Rufus I rebooted my computer and tried to select the Ubuntu live USB from the boot menu, but my USB was not there.

I also disabled/enabled the Secure Boot option and I wrote the image as both dd and iso file formats. It never sees the USB. The interesting thing is when I delete the Ubuntu image and write a Manjaro image instead, there is no problem. I can boot the Manjaro image. I want to install Ubuntu, so what should I do?

System Information:

8th Gen Intel Core i7 8750H
  Nvidia GeForce GTX1050 4GB
  8GB DDR4 RAM

Comment: What is the full name of the .iso file you tried?

Comment: ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64 @JasonF4

Comment: Interesting.   Maybe somebody else here can help.  Upvoted.

Comment: I think you will have a better chance at getting an answer if you say Manjoro will boot with the same media in the title.

Comment: Thanks, i edited the title